# facebook fql query returning null on page_fan

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app on facebook that asks for user_likes permissions, and afterwards checks whether a user has liked a particular page on facebook.  It works great on 80% of users, but has problems with the rest:

when running this fql query:

```
"SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' and uid = me()"
```

the response is null.  These users have granted all the necessary permissions to the app.
what might be the case?

Comment: Could it simply be that those users aren't fans of the page in question?

Comment: nope. I've checked it in the first place

Answer (score 1):

It's due privacy settings. Some people don't use "public" like settings, that's all. Tested.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So, even if i ask them to give the permission, it won't work? Shouldn't it return something at least in that case? like:  access_denied, or user_made_his_likes_private_even_if_u_ask_permission   ?